# Print SVG file correctly scaled

Tags: printing, svg, inkscape

I've developed an SVG file using Inkscape. The object is 16cm large, but when I print it from Inkscape, it is just ~3cm small. How to print an SVG file correctly scaled?

Comment: SVG's are "Scalable" (that's the "S").  So there should be no "correct scale".  Is this image you want to print an actual SVG, or is it an image (JPG, etc.) imported into the SVG?  Are you rendering it as a Vector, or Bitmap when printing?  What DPI are you printing at?

Comment: It is a vector graphic. If you have a problem with the "correctly scaled", please read it as "scaled so the printed result has an exactly defined size".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've found a way to get an exact print:

- export to bitmap from Inkscape, e.g. using 600dpi
- use IrfanView to print the resulting bitmap file (IrfanView can print it at the size stored in the graphic file)

Answer (score 0):

You should correctly set `viewBox=` attribute.

See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/116159/100215